# Fat Models or Controllers in Ember

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, ember.js

It seems that the implementation of 'MVC' in Ember is slightly different than that which I have grown accustomed. It feels as though the flow in Ember encourages business logic to be placed in the controller. Is this the intent, or simply the confused result of many outdated, or short-hand examples, tutorials and fiddles?

PS: These "outdated or shorthand" examples have all been invaluable in their time, and I do wholly appreciate the efforts of their authors :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The MVC architecture of Ember isn't direclty comparable to that of a typical web app. The main difference is that the server MVC architecture only really deals with a request scope, while the ember app doesn't have a notion of requests. The whole app is available, or not at all.

The server-side code mainly does model manipulation and notifications, and so having a fat model/thin controllers makes sense. The controller is essentially the router to the model.

If you see Ember's controller as a *model-proxy*, it makes more sense in making the controller fat. All the logic is delegated to the controller, and the model is really just there to serve objects. Here's a simplified layout.

*Server side architecture*

```
View       - Displays information
Controller - Delegates request to relevant model, 
             calls the appropriate view with relevant (manipulated) data
Model      - (Fat) Most of the application's thinking happens here,
             calls the database for records
(database) - Serves records as requested
```

*Ember Architecture*

```
Router        - Sets up which template/view/controller to use for the page
Template/View - Displays information from the controller
Controller    - All interactive logic goes here,
                interacts with model for records
Model         - Record store which calls server side api for additional records
```

As you can see, the ember model should be seen more like the server-side database function, while the ember controller is more like the the server-side controller.

Have a look at [Core Concepts](http://emberjs.com/guides/concepts/core-concepts/) and the [Introduction to Controllers](http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/) on the ember page for more information.

Comment: Brilliant! Thats the answer I was hoping for, and well explained. Cheers!